# VBA Loop through multiple sheets to output formulas in multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I write decently sloppy code and piecemeal together various things I find online to help me accomplish what needs to be done. This loop goes through 4 different worksheets to paste a formula in 3 columns. Based on some previous feedback from the site, I removed all of my `.Select` references and hopefully did things more cleanly. 2 questions that I have:

1) Can anyone think of a way I can further optimize this to have it run more quickly?

2) Is there a better way to define my RRSData!A2:O10000 formula.  I just chose 10,000 because there shouldn't be that many in the future, but its obviously working harder than it needs to now since there are only ~1000 rows currently.

```
Dim LastRow1 As Long, i1 As Long, InxW As Long
Dim wsNames As Variant

wsNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")

For InxW = LBound(wsNames) To UBound(wsNames)
   With Worksheets(wsNames(InxW))
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i1 = 25 To LastRow
            With Range("KA1").Offset(i1 - 1, 0)
                .Formula = "=IF(SUMIF(RRSData!$A$2:$O$10000,OFFSET($KA$1,CELL(""row"",THIS),-285),RRSData!$M$2:$M$10000)>0,SUMIF(RRSData!$A$2:$O$10000,OFFSET($KA$1,CELL(""row"",THIS),-285),RRSData!$M$2:$M$10000),"""")"
                .NumberFormat = "0.00"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
            With Range("KB1").Offset(i1 - 1, 0)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",If(RC[-1]>1.1,""High"",If(RC[-1]<0.8,""Low"",""Neutral"")))"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
            With Range("KC1").Offset(i1 - 1, 0)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]="""","""",IF(RC[-2]>1.1,""+5%"",IF(RC[-2]<0.8,""-5%"",""0%"")))"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        Next i1
    End With
Next InxW
```

The code works, but it takes probably 2 minutes to loop through the four sheets, and the total number of rows across the four sheets is <500

Comment: What is the aim of your code? Your title doesn't state that. In the body of your text you can state that looping is slow and with a descriptive title we'd have a better idea of what you're doing and how to best help. https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions/2437#2437 is one of the links available in the top right when you click the `Ask Question` button. With more information we can give you a better and more thorough review.

Comment: @IvenBach Thanks for the tip, I have updated the title to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of tips.

When using `With`, make sure that you correctly reference the subordinate lines. Check the following example.

```
With Range("KA1").Offset(i1 - 1, 0) '<--- You have ...
With .Range("KA1").Offset(i1 - 1, 0) ' ... should be
```

Consider using `FillDown` or some similar command to do bulk edits. This will save looping, especially the loop that flips between the VBA engine and the Excel engine (which is expensive time-wise). Normally I suggest using arrays, but your use of formula suggests this other way.

The following example has not been tested.

```
Dim formulaOneRange as Range
    Set formulaOneRange = .Range("KA25:KA" & lastRow)
    With formulaOneRange
        .Formula = "=IF(SUMIF(RRSData!$A$2:$O$10000,OFFSET($KA$1,CELL(""row"",THIS),-285),RRSData!$M$2:$M$10000)>0,SUMIF(RRSData!$A$2:$O$10000,OFFSET($KA$1,CELL(""row"",THIS),-285),RRSData!$M$2:$M$10000),"""")"
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Set formulaOneRange = .Range("KB25:KB" & lastRow)
    With formulaOneRange
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",If(RC[-1]>1.1,""High"",If(RC[-1]<0.8,""Low"",""Neutral"")))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Set formulaOneRange = .Range("KC25:KC" & lastRow)
    With formulaOneRange
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",If(RC[-1]>1.1,""High"",If(RC[-1]<0.8,""Low"",""Neutral"")))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
```

Of course, the code could be tidies up a bit as per below, but I thought the extra lines will show my thinking a bit more clearly.

```
' My example code above ... 
Set formulaOneRange = .Range("KC25:KC" & lastRow)
With formulaOneRange

' Could be ....
With .Range("KC25:KC" & lastRow)
```

Also, defining the range in an easy to manage variable would assist if you wanted to use `FillDown` or do some other manipulation within each section.